# How to check with LocalDateTime that a given time is within 24 hours of now using Scala

Tags: java, scala, localdatetime

I want to create a method which takes one parameter and returns true if the the date provided is within 24 hours of the current time.

```
def compareDates(date: LocalDateTime): Boolean = {
  val now = LocalDateTime.now
  date.compareTo(now)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `isBefore` and `isAfter` (closed range):

```
!(date.isAfter(now.plusDays(1)) || date.isBefore(now.minusDays(1)))
```

For open range:

```
date.isBefore(now.plusDays(1)) && date.isAfter(now.minusDays(1))
```